# how come iterating through unordered_map but cannot change its mapped value?

Tags: c++

```
pair<bool, char> pos_panlindrome(unordered_map<char, int>& smap){
    for(auto m : smap){
        m.second /= 2;
   }
}
```

Where I declared smap in another function calling pos_panlindrome. I want all the mapped value (in spite of the key value) to be halved. But somehow, when I print out the smap after pos_panlindrome function, none of the mapped_value got changed.

Why is that case?

Comment: You forgot the reference in the for loop `for(auto m : smap) => for(auto& m : smap)`

Comment: in `auto m : smap`, `m` is a copy. You want a reference if the change is to apply to the original. `auto & m : smap`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're using an unmodified `auto` in your for loop.  This creates a copy of each map element, and then you modify the copy.  You need a reference if you want to change the entry in the map.  Try this instead:

```
for (auto& m : smap)
{
  m.second /= 2;
}
```

Comment: Solution is correct, but bad wording in the explanation. This has nothing to do with `auto` and everything to do with the reference.

Comment: What would be better?  "naked auto?"  "unqualified auto?"

Comment: "The problem is that you're not using a reference in your for loop."

Comment: A comment and a closure is more suited to this question than the answer.

Comment: @SergeyA or flag as dupe